# How to detect Word.Application.SaveAs timeouts?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a VBS script that converts a bunch of word (doc, dox, and docm) and powerpoint (pptx) files into PDFs, via Word and PowerPoint application objects and argument `SaveAs`.

That works fine, but for reasons unknown the processing fails for some Word files (guess: the files were created with another office version, or have some corruption). `SaveAs` runs indefinitely, with Word running using 100% of a CPU core, until I kill it manually.

After the `SaveAs` operation has ran for a programmed amount of time (say 5 minutes), I'd like to:

1. Abort the current `SaveAs` operation.
2. Raise an error.

I could then dispatch an error message via mail, then proceed to the next file (by specifying `On Error Resume Next`).

This code excerpt shows how I convert Word files to PDF in the script:

```
Dim  oWord, Pres
Set oWord   = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Pres    = oWord.Documents.Open("/path/to/file.docm", , , msoFalse)
Pres.SaveAs "/path/to/file.pdf", 17, True 'runs forever on certain files
Pres.Close 0
```

How can I abort the current `SaveAs` operation after a specified delay has elapsed?

Comment: Consider adding to your post what you've tried and what if any errors you got.

Comment: @ F Rowe have not tried anything, got no lead on where to start because I don't know how to get a time out handle.

Comment: As @FRowe was asking, you could [edit] and add the code that works, except for the timeout part.

Comment: @Flakes Okay, added a code excerpt.

Comment: You may launch the part of VBS code which saves the document in separate wscript.exe process and control elapsed time from main process.

Comment: That's an idea indeed, thanks. However, I'd rather avoid it if possible. The script is deployed on servers and runs on hundreds of files,only a handful of which may cause problems. Something with `Exec` would run instetaneously, so I'd have to add delays not to launch 100's of winword processes etc.